# Placing 4” LED in the external soffit of the house with no ground

Tags: light-fixture, light

I’m trying to install 4 inch cannless LED lights in the soffit under the roof of my house. Unfortunately there is no room for the junction box which is at least 1 1/2 inches thick. I took the motherboard out of the junction box and decreased the space to almost half an inch. But I don’t have room for the ground wire. I’m not an expert Electrician but I have some knowledge. Can someone advise if this is safe and or can it be done

> [image]

Comment: Modifying the device invalidates the UL listing. If it's ever found in a fire investigation, your insurance company may use that to invalidate your claim...

Comment: *A little knowledge is a dangerous thing*, as the saying goes...

Answer (score 2):

High Voltage needs to be handled in the usual methods: Don't modify the units, use junction boxes, follow manufacturer's instructions, follow code, etc.

You might do better getting some LED lights that run on low voltage, then you can run the low voltage wire where you need in very small spaces, and the LED driver can be deeper inside the house where a junction box or outlet can be provided per code and manufacturer instructions without modifying the units.

Comment: Line voltage, really. It's not kilovolts. Still plenty to burn the house down or otherwise cause problems if you make your own rules, of course.